# HTTP Status 404 - Why server can't find my servlet I mapped to?

Tags: java, xml, servlets, server

*First of all, sorry if this question is a bit longer. I promise the code is super simple and fast to read.*

I made a very simple app using *Servlets*. It has *form* where *user* picks beer color. It should take him to *servlet* I mapped to using *XML*. *Servlet* should just send a *response* back and print the color user picked.

Unfortunately, I have a bug somewhere and I can't understand where. Could someone help me, as I am really stuck?

There are my three files:

**form.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <form action="SelectBeer.do" method="POST">

        Color:
        <select name="color">
            <option>light</option>
            <option>amber</option>
            <option>brown</option>
            <option>dark</option>
        </select>
        
        <button>Submit</button>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**BeerSelect.java** servlet:

```
package com.example.web;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class BeerSelect extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        String color = req.getParameter("color");
        out.println("Selected: " + color);

    }
}
```

**web.xml**, that I used for mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>MyBeerApp</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.example.web.BeerSelect</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/SelectBeer.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  
</web-app>
```

Lastly, I will provide you with ss from my project structure. Once again, thanks in advance for anyone who tries to help. It would mean a lot to me!

[image]

P.S. Form runs fine, but when I submit it, I get 404 error.

Comment: have you try to open browser developer tools to inspect what is the URL when click on the submit button? This might help to check does it access the correct URL or not

Comment: It is `http://localhost:8080/MyBeerApp/SelectBeer.do`. And in XML I am using url-pattern of `/SelectBeer.do`, which should be fine, right?

Comment: try recompiling the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Stefan This is my project structure. I found it to be a bit different from you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your code wrong. I have tried run and result as your expect.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't believe it. How can it work for you and not for me? I tired it several times, still no luck. I get error 404 every single time. Do you have same project structure as well?

Comment: Yes. It is the same your project. Can you send your project for me?

Comment: I just wrote it all over again. I noticed one difference. I needed to put HTML in WebContent and XML in WEB-INF. There go my 4 hours...

Comment: Can you do me favor and check your project structure again? The one I posted in question's picture is wrong, right? I mean it can't possibly work if you did it as I did before?

Comment: Thanks again, you can delete this answer now :) I accepted your 2nd